# Implementing anonymous authentication and double voting prevention

Tags: authentication, voting

I am thinking for ways to implement a mechanism which enables a user to vote,without logging any of his details. Each user has a set of attributes that enable him to vote. For eg. Id,name,email-id.

Using these attributes we must guarantee that the user can vote for the first time. During this time,complete anonymity is guaranteed.

But if the user comes for a second time to vote,he should not be allowed to vote. Is this remotely possible?We are not storing any of the information related to the user.No ip adddress,email-id or student id. They are just used as a means of authentication.

I read many research papers for this but not able to find anything specific.

Comment: So basically your problem is reduced to `can I determine if a person has been here before without having any knowledge of the person whatsoever?`

Comment: programming aside how would you ever be able to do that anywhere? not knowing anything of the person also includes not knowing if they've voted before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a mechanism which enables a user to vote,without logging any of his
>   details

Sure you can. Just don't log anything. But you do need to *store* information about which user has voted. You actually need info of the user not even the machine the user used as the user could vote from another machine.

Comment: :but that approach would induce some insecurity. Because if we log the details, then if someone has access to this log,they can deduce who did what. Which would break the original purpose of complete anonymity

Comment: As I said dont log it.Save it e.g. in a database.